# How to acquire the source from a MuleEvent?

Tags: java, mule

I'm using Mule 3.2.1 with java 6.  I am writing some code to process an exception event and I would like to get at this information:

```
event.source.statusLine

where
event is a MuleEvent
source is a org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod
statusLine is a org.apache.commons.httpclient.StatusLine
```

I see the data in that path under the debugger, but I cannot find a way to get the source data in the MuleEvent.

Any ideas how I can get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `org.mule.api.MuleEvent` source is a `java.net.URI` so I doubt it's what you're after.

I'm going to take a wild guess: I suppose you get an exception after interacting with an outbound HTTP endpoint.

If that is the case, the `GetMethod` instance is actually accessible with `muleEvent.getMessage().getPayload()` (`#[message.payload]` in MEL).

Comment: That was it.  Thank-you.  Here's what I implemented:  GetMethod getMethod = (GetMethod)event.getMessage().getPayload();